# Got some issues with a case in my reducer

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

im working on a react native project and ive got a small bug. What im trying to do is edit some notes that are fairly deeply nested in an object.
what i expect to happen is that it goes into characters, finds the correct character then finding the correct scene related to said character before adding the text. What returns is for each letter added it will copy every single part of the state. 
Reducer:

```
`case EDIT_SCENENOTES:
            console.log(state)
            return {
                ...state,
                    currentProduction: {
                        ...state.currentProduction,
                        characters:
                            state.currentProduction.characters.map(charObj => charObj.id === action.CharacterId ?
                                {
                                    ...charObj,
                                    scenes: charObj.scenes.map(correctScene => correctScene.sceneId === action.SceneId ?
                                        {
                                            ...correctScene,
                                            [action.sceneName]:action.sceneObject
                                        }:state),
                                }:state)

                    }
                };
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant code in text format in the question instead of linking to an external image?

Comment: Yes ofc, sorry bout that

Comment: Your `else` case of the ternary operators are returning the `state`, which instead should be the original of what you're mapping?

Comment: @Yuya TY you were  right. returning the original of the map fixed it. Thx to you the last function of my app is done. Im also starting to regret the fact that i didnt flatten my state more.